# Prove that for every integer $n\geq 0$ it follows that $24 | (5^{2n})-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

- Prove that for every integer $n\geq 0$ it follows that $24 | (5^{2n})-1$

Clearly, we have $24 | (5^{2n})=25^n$. How can I prove this question, can you help? Thanks...

Comment: Do you mean $$24|5^{2n}-1$$?

Comment: I don't know, there can be a typo. If there is a typo, then can you edit the question?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Probably, yes.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written, we have $5^{2n}-1=25^n-1=(25-1)(25^{n-1}-25^{n-2}+\cdots+1)$, which has $24$ as a factor. We are using $$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+\cdots +b^{n-1})$$

Answer (score 1):

$25\equiv 1\pmod{24}\implies 25^{n}\equiv 1\pmod{24}$

Or you can try $(a-b)\big|(a^n-b^n)\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z},n\in\mathbb{N}$. So, $(25-1)\big|(25^n-1^n)$

That is $25^n$ leaves remainder $1$ when divided by $24$.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1):

By Factor Theorem, $x^n-1$ is divisible by $x-1$.

Put $x=25$.

Answer (score 0):

Using binomial theorem we can write:

$$5^{2n}-1=25^n-1=(24+1)^n-1= 24k+1-1=24k$$

Answer (score 0):

$n \ge 0$:

$(5^2)^n -1= (1+24)^n-1=$

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}24^k-1=$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} 24^k $.